# share image on linkedin after login in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I have use this code for share text and image on LinkedIn:-

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares"];
  OAMutableURLRequest *request =
  [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                            consumer:[self getConsumer]
                               token:self.accesstoken
                            callback:nil
                   signatureProvider:nil];

  NSDictionary *update = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:

                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"anyone",@"code",nil], @"visibility",

                    @"comment goes here", @"comment",
                    [[NSDictionary alloc]
                     initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                    @"description goes here",@"description",
                    @"www.google.com",@"submittedUrl",
                      @"title goes here",@"title",
                    @"http://economy.blog.ocregister.com/files/2009/01/linkedin-logo.jpg",@"submittedImageUrl",nil],@"content",
                    nil];
  [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  NSString *updateString = [update JSONString];
  [request setHTTPBodyWithString:updateString];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
  [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                 delegate:self
        didFinishSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish:)
          didFailSelector:@selector(postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:)];
```

But I have errors on:-  consumer:[self getConsumer] , token:self.accesstoken and not found these methods postUpdateApiCallResult:didFinish: , postUpdateApiCallResult:didFail:

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried and explain what issues you are having.

Comment: My issue is :- Now I want to share image and text on linkedin